# Create dict based on queryset result

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Imagine I get some queryset:

```
my_queryset_result = ...values('my_column').distinct()
```

if I print it it comes out like:

```
<QuerySet[{'my_column':'foo'}{'my_column':'bar'}]>
```

I need to create a dictionary with the result, like this:

```
{'foo':0, 'bar':0}
```

Can it be done? Or should I use a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [official django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values) `.values()` returns a `list of dict`. To acheive your requirement to the following,

```
out_dict = {}
for item in my_queryset_result:
    out_dict.update({item['my_column']: 0})
```

I'm not sure whether this an efficient way or not :( But, you will get the required dict in `out_dict`